# How to run Visual Studio (Win7) remotely from a Linux box?

Tags: windows, linux, remote-desktop, visual-studio-2010

I have a Linux desktop that is just easier to program on (for me) than a laptop.  I have a laptop running Windows 7 that I want to write some programs (C++/C#) with VS on the remote laptop.  What are my alternatives and/or the best practice for getting a full remote Windows gui display on linux?  Kubuntu, if that matters.

p.s. I don't want to go the virtual machine route to program in VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you can share Windows 7 desktop [like this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404238.aspx) and connect from Linux with RDP client (rdesktop )
- another option is some free online service like [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx)
- VNC server / client is another option